# How to pass token generated by java code in karate test case?

Tags: java, spring-boot, karate, spring-boot-test

2 types of test cases I have written:

1. Using spring boot
2. Karate framework

[image]

To access the endpoints, valid token is required and I am generating the token using spring boot[image] test. I want to use the same token for karate framework but not sure how to pass it as a parameter so that I will use it in my feature file. We are using client-credentials for auth.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QURQq.jpg)
I want to pass token in below mentioned karate test case:

[image]

Comment: I was thinking, was not it easier to take a snapshot from your screen or copy the text and paste it?

Comment: to OP, please spend some time and read the documentation: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#calling-java - then look at other answers on stack overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkarate%5D+java+parameter

Comment: Please post your code as text, NOT as images.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Our team was using the java code to generate the JWT token so I just called that java method in my karate test case and it worked.

Note: We have an option to call java method in our karate test case. I was not aware about it.